# Python Slice a List Using a List of Multiple Tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, slice

I have a list of numbers that I would like to slice the range of numbers that is given from a list of multiple tuples. For example, I have a list that looks like:

```
my_list = [ 5, 8, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 8, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21, 34, 25, 91, 61, 0, 0,]
```

I also have a list of tuples that are the indicies of values that that I want that looks like:

```
my_tups = [(5,9), (14,18)]
```

How would I return only the values of my_list using my_tups as an index?

Answer (score 4):

Using list comprehension:

```
my_list = [ 5, 8, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 8, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21, 34, 25, 91, 61, 0, 0,]
my_tups = [(5,9), (14,18)]

new_list = [my_list[i:j] for i,j in my_tups]
```

---

After your comment:

```
my_list = [ 5, 8, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 8, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21, 34, 25, 91, 61, 0, 0]
my_tups = [(5,9), (14,18)]

new_list = [0 for i in my_list] # Create a list filled with zeros

for i,j in my_tups:
    new_list[i:j] = my_list[i:j] # Replace items with items from my_list using the indexes from my_tups
```

Output:

```
>>> new_list
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21, 34, 25, 91, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: This seems the most simple and logical solution to me

Comment: @Chris_Rands and fastest

Comment: @Kate do you mean [0,0,0,0,0,1,3,4,8,13,0,0,0,0,21,34, 25,91,0,0,0] (3 zeros at the end instead of 2)?

Comment: Yes I forgot to add one

Answer (score 1):

You can use the builtin [slice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) as follows

```
my_list = [5, 8, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 8, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21, 34, 25, 91, 61, 0, 0]
my_tups = [(5, 9), (14, 18)]

my_list2 = [my_list[slice(*o)] for o in my_tups]
print(my_list2)

>>> [[1, 3, 4, 8], [21, 34, 25, 91]]
```

Answer (score 0):

a possibility

```
from itertools import chain

my_iter = chain(*[my_list[start:end] for start, end in my_tups])

[l for l in my_iter]
```

gives

```
[1, 3, 4, 8, 21, 34, 25, 91]
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! Is there a way to return the list with zeros filled in around the numbers? So the final result is [0,0,0,0,0,1,3,4,8,13,0,0,0,0,21,34, 25,91,61,0,0]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to return the values from `my_list` in the ranges `5:9` and `14:18`. The following code should do it

```
my_list = [ 5, 8, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 8, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21, 34, 25, 91, 61, 0, 0]
my_tups = [(5,9), (14,18)]

def flattens(lists):
    return sum(lists, [])
flatten([my_list[lo:hi] for (lo, hi) in my_tups])
# gives [1, 3, 4, 8, 21, 34, 25, 91]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `slice` with [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap):

```
from itertools import starmap

my_list = [ 5., 8., 3., 0., 0., 1., 3., 4., 8., 13., 0., 0., 0., 0., 21., 34., 25., 91., 61., 0., 0.]
my_tups = [(5,9), (14,18)]

result = [my_list[slc] for slc in starmap(slice, my_tups)]
# [[1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 8.0], [21.0, 34.0, 25.0, 91.0]]
```

---

With `starmap`, you could add a *step* parameter to *any* of your slices arbitrarily:

```
>>> my_tups = [(5,9,2), (14,18)] # step first slice by 2
>>> [my_list[slc] for slc in starmap(slice, my_tups)]
[[1.0, 4.0], [21.0, 34.0, 25.0, 91.0]]
```

Comment: You should however ask that as a new question

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
for a, b in my_tups:
    print(my_list[a:b])
```

Instead of printing you can do something else with the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this on a list comprehension

```
slices = [my_list[x:y] for x, y in my_tups if x < len(my_list) and y < len(my_list)]
```